# Most efficient way to process complex histogram data?

Tags: c++, performance, qt, data-structures

I'm currently implementing a histogram that will show a very large scale data using Qt and I have some doubts about which data structure(s) I should be using for my problem. I will be displaying the amount of queries received from users of an application and the way I should display is as follows -in a single application that will show different histograms upon clicking different "show me this data etc." buttons-

1) Display the histogram of total queries per every month -4 months of data here, I
kept four variables and incremented them as I caught queries belonging to those months
in the CSV file-

2) Display the histogram of total queries per every single day in a selected month -I was thinking of using 4 QVectors to represent the months for this one, incrementing every element of the vector (day), as I come by that specific day -e.g. the vector represents the month of August and whenever I come across a data with 2011-08-XY , I will increment the (XY + 1)th element of that vector by 1- my second alternative is to use 4 QLinkedList's for the sake of better complexity but I'm not sure if the ways I've come up with are efficient enough and I'm willing to listen to any other idea.

3) Here's where things get a bit complicated. Display the histogram of total queries per every hour in a selected day and month. The data represented is multiplied in a vast manner and I don't know which data structure -or combination of structures- I should use to implement this one. A list of lists perhaps?

Any ideas on my problems at 2) and 3) would be helpful, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it shouldn't be too unmanageable to always do queries per hour. Assuming that the number of queries per hour is never greater than the maximum int value, that's only 24 ints per day = 32 bits or 64 depending on your machine. Assuming 32 bits, then you could get up to 28 years worth of data per MB.

There's no need to transfer the month/year - your program can work that out. Just assign hour 0 to the earliest point in your data, which you keep as a constant, then work out the date based on hours passed since then.

This avoids having to have a list of lists or anything fancy - just use an array where each address contains the number of hours since hour 0, and the number of queries for that hour.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use a classical database? 
When you start asking these kind of question I think it is a good time to consider a more robust structure.There are multiple data structures implemented inside any DB, optimized either for different access type.  You should considerate at least lookup, insertion, deletion, range queries. There is no structure which is better than the others in all costs, so there is always a trade-off.

Qt has [some database classes](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/database.html) you can use. I never used the Qt SQL library, but I think you should give it a shot. Fortunately, there is a Qt SQL programming guide at the end of the page linked.